# simplexml_load_string function not read soap code

Tags: php, soap

I have following code :

```
    $result = <<<XML
    $flight
    XML;


    $soap = simplexml_load_string($result, NULL, NULL, "http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v25_0");
    $soap->registerXPathNamespace('air', 'http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v25_0');
    $test = $soap->xpath('//air:lowfaresearchrsp/air:airsegmentlist/air:airsegment');

    foreach ($test as $keyO => $valueO) {
        echo "<br/>****************************************<br/>", $keyO;
        foreach ($valueO->attributes() as $key => $value) {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $key, " - ", $value;
        }
    }
```

The `$flight` is a huge soap string generated by `curl_exec()` function.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:body>
   <air:lowfaresearchrsp xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v25_0" xmlns:common_v25_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v25_0" currencytype="AUD" distanceunits="MI" responsetime="17105" transactionid="24B931EB0A0764774D967B23E7F522CB">
     <common_v25_0:responsemessage providercode="ACH" type="Error" code="700003">[ACH] Provider error: Provider transaction failed.</common_v25_0:responsemessage>
     <common_v25_0:responsemessage providercode="RCH" type="Error" code="701815">UserId,Password element(s) is/are missing in RCH Access Context.</common_v25_0:responsemessage>
     <air:flightdetailslist>
        <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="1" originterminal="2E" equipment="332" distance="3635" traveltime="520" flighttime="520" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T11:15:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T08:35:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="W57MJ5UPR3eKNycFDbvLHg==">
           <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="1" originterminal="2E" equipment="332" distance="3635" traveltime="515" flighttime="515" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T13:25:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T10:50:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="ZEprJLEGTPO5oKYbj0/8Ug==">
              <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="1" originterminal="2E" equipment="772" distance="3635" traveltime="510" flighttime="510" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T19:05:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T16:35:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="M2uITHooRlWN00a5Cf/esQ==">
                 <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="4" originterminal="2E" equipment="333" distance="3635" traveltime="510" flighttime="510" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T13:10:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T10:40:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="jl/0uOIRT3KG+qfJjfJMTQ==">
                    <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="1" originterminal="2E" equipment="388" distance="3635" traveltime="505" flighttime="505" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T16:20:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T13:55:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="LuzIXux/TmmbnuJZ9Gb23Q==">
                       <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="1" originterminal="2E" equipment="772" distance="3635" traveltime="500" flighttime="500" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T21:30:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T19:10:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="CDG" key="5BsjozbmT32Kw/zkkfdHJg==">
                          <air:flightdetails originterminal="2F" equipment="320" distance="247" traveltime="75" flighttime="75" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T15:40:00.000+01:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T14:25:00.000+01:00" destination="AMS" origin="CDG" key="t1PCkMniRSKw+zPsWsIjvQ==">
                             <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="4" equipment="74M" distance="3639" traveltime="595" flighttime="500" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T19:35:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T17:15:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="AMS" key="1r0XtTf+TvmXv64vgwAcLA==">
                                <air:flightdetails originterminal="2F" equipment="737" distance="247" traveltime="85" flighttime="85" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T11:45:00.000+01:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T10:20:00.000+01:00" destination="AMS" origin="CDG" key="cJHWqypWQ7K+EiK6gAg/uw==">
                                   <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="4" equipment="777" distance="3639" traveltime="595" flighttime="495" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T15:40:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T13:25:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="AMS" key="uc1ZFD5ISWG5u2vnTMl2HA==">
                                      <air:flightdetails originterminal="2F" equipment="321" distance="247" traveltime="80" flighttime="80" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T08:35:00.000+01:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T07:15:00.000+01:00" destination="AMS" origin="CDG" key="aTo+uIuHSj6gAhAgDjFPUg==">
                                         <air:flightdetails destinationterminal="4" equipment="333" distance="3639" traveltime="628" flighttime="508" arrivaltime="2014-11-14T13:03:00.000-05:00" departuretime="2014-11-14T10:35:00.000+01:00" destination="JFK" origin="AMS" key="9Nex3zh7RF6CPdrY1NhR1Q==">
```

...

I expected :

`****************************************
0
availabilitysource - AvailStatusTTY
optionalservicesindicator - false
participantlevel - Airline Source
changeofplane - false
equipment - 332
eticketability - Yes
distance - 3635
flighttime - 520
arrivaltime - 2014-11-14T11:15:00.000-05:00
departuretime - 2014-11-14T08:35:00.000+01:00
destination - JFK
origin - CDG
flightnumber - 1022
carrier - DL
group - 0
key - GtjA5xmlS22U96KdftKeJQ==

---

1
availabilitysource - AvailStatusTTY
optionalservicesindicator - false
participantlevel - Airline Source
changeofplane - false
equipment - 332
eticketability - Yes
distance - 3635
flighttime - 515
arrivaltime - 2014-11-14T13:25:00.000-05:00
departuretime - 2014-11-14T10:50:00.000+01:00
destination - JFK
origin - CDG
flightnumber - 1023
carrier - DL
group - 0
key - vXNcJ/8iR/qKKO35/7sLoQ==

---

....`

But got nothing.

When I paste xml code in here

```
    $result = <<<XML
    $flight
    XML;
```

instead of `$flight`, it's working properly like what I expected. Please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your pasted code and original code. Some times it might be have uppercases also. When you copy them from firebug or any other editor, the code automatically converts to standard type.

My suggestion is change this

`$test = $soap->xpath('//air:lowfaresearchrsp/air:airsegmentlist/air:airsegment');`

like

`$test = $soap->xpath('//air:LowfareSearchRsp/air:AirsegmentList/air:Airsegment');`